# error when trying to brew postinstall python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

I need `pip3`, so I'm trying to `brew install python3` because it's included. I ran into this error (which appears to involve the system python) and the `brew postinstall python3` failed.

I tried removing the python3 installed by homebrew, but that did not help any.

I ran:

```
brew remove python3; brew install python3;
```

It says that the install failed didn't finish, so I ran:

```
brew postinstall python3
```

Here's the output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/python3
-s
setup.py
--no-user-cfg
install
--force
--verbose
--install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin
--install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
--single-version-externally-managed
--record=installed.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 371, in __getattr__
    return cls._member_map_[name]
KeyError: '_convert'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    exec(init_file.read(), command_ns)
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/libexec/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/libexec/setuptools/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/libexec/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/libexec/setuptools/setuptools/depends.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import compat
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/libexec/setuptools/setuptools/compat.py", line 45, in <module>
    import http.client as httplib
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 73, in <module>
    IntEnum._convert(
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 373, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _convert

Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: It's unclear what your error message reflects: what command did you use, where in your description of installing Python3 and uninstalling it does it occur, etc.

Comment: I ran `brew remove python3; brew install python3;` It says that the install failed didn't finish, so I run `brew postinstall python3`. It then gives the error above.

Comment: Is there an explicit `PYTHONPATH` set? That could well explain why those 2.7 libraries/modules are picked up.

Comment: Setting the `PYTHONPATH` fixed it, thanks.

How do I accept that answer?

Comment: Did you *set* the `PYTHONPATH`, or *unset* it? The proper solution would usually mean to unset it. If you did not unset it, to what value did you set it?

Comment: I set it, not unset. I set it to `usr/local/:$PYTHONPATH`.  Unsetting it gave an empty value for `echo $PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: You should unset it. There should be no need for setting your PYTHONPATH, unless you explicitly have installed some packages somewhere else. `/usr/local/bin/python3` knows where to find its own packages. (Note that `usr/local/`, or probably `/usr/local/` is what you meant, doesn't really make sense as a place to have Python packages installed anyway.)